# how to update database field using variable in php?

Tags: php, mysql, variables

Hi i am trying to update a  database field using php  variable but i am   getting an error

Here is my code

**update.php**

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'root';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$item=11;
$items = implode(",",$_REQUEST['cbox']);


$query=mysql_query('UPDATE form_elemen '.
            'SET interest = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($item).'" '.
            'WHERE id = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($item).'"');
mysql_select_db('helixdemo');
$retval = mysql_query( $query, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Updated data successfully\n";
echo $items;
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

i am getting following error

```
Could not update data: Query was empty
```

Where i am wrong please tell me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which error are you getting?

Comment: If you're getting a "No database selected error", try placing `mysql_select_db('helixdemo');` just under your DB connection.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  i am getting this error "Could not update data: Query was empty"

Comment: OK. Well, I see `$items` which doesn't seem to be used anywhere, it's just being echo'ed.  Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: i tried this also but not working

Comment: You probably meant to use `SET interest = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($items)` instead of `SET interest = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($item)`

Comment: it is showing undefined variable how it is possible

Comment: I need to know the "exact" error message and see my other comment above.

Comment: exact error msg is    "
Notice: Undefined variable: query in E:\xampp\htdocs\updatetable\update\update.php on line 20
Could not update data: Query was empty"

Comment: OK, try this `$query = mysql_query('UPDATE form_elemen '.
            'SET interest = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($item).'" '.
            'WHERE id = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($item).'"');` it needs to be set to the `$query` variable. Should fix it.

Comment: Please post the error

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_query()` executes your query string immediately, and returns a result handle. You have

```
mysql_query("UPDATE ....");
mysql_query($query);
```

Where you've NEVER defined `$query`. Perhaps you mean

```
$query = "UPDATE ...";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

strong textYou are doing things wrong.Just assign the `$query=mysql_query`.Another thing which i found is that you are selecting database afterwards please select it before running your mysql_query and Why to be so complicated in `mysql_query`.You need to add $conn when using `mysql_select_db()`. Use the code below

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'root';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('helixdemo',$conn);
$item=11;
$items = implode(",",$_REQUEST['cbox']);


$query=mysql_query("UPDATE form_elemen SET interest = 'mysql_real_escape_string($item)' WHERE id = 'mysql_real_escape_string($item)'");

$retval = mysql_query( $query, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Updated data successfully\n";
echo $items;
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: I founded what was the problem now please check my answer again and use my given code